# google-maps-react - Specific Pins not Showing up until Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

**SparkNotes:**

I'm pulling in a crime API to see hotspots. Certain crimes will not be logged with a lat/long, therefore, are not shown up in standard (free) crime apps.

- Lat/Long pins I've overridden to a new lat/long don't show up on
  first load/or at all.  (google-maps-react) (Confirmed lat/long is valid per crimes in near areas.)
- Normal pins that had an existing lat/long show
  up fine/show up as soon as it loads. (Even though it's all the same array of data.)
- I loop through the blank lat/long and replace the lat/long with a rough lat/long of the area just so it shows up. In my console log I can confirm that I've overriden the blank lat/long.
- I want these records to understand the neighborhoods/potentially avoid moving into a hotspot of specific crimes.

**API Normal:**
https://data.seattle.gov/resource/tazs-3rd5.json?$limit=20000&$offset=20000&$order=offense_id

**Specific Items:**
https://data.seattle.gov/resource/tazs-3rd5.json?$where=report_number%20in(%272020-022388%27,%272020-044620%27,%272020-043813%27,%272020-029645%27,%272020-901621%27)

**Full Use Case (Which doesn't work for at all pins):** https://data.seattle.gov/resource/tazs-3rd5.json?crime_against_category=PERSON&mcpp=MAGNOLIA&offense_parent_group=SEX%20OFFENSES

**Request for help:**
Can someone please help on how to get these overridden pins to show up consistently?

**Things I've Tried:**
Force update/having multiple refreshes etc/decreasing async time. Those work for when I put in specific crime report number, but if I search for kidnapping/peeping tom, they will not pull with the rest of the person crimes.

I can confirm that if I just load every crime in that API, the map logs all of them (except the ones I need), It's like a pin per foot of street, but the pins in the categories I need don't show up. (So I don't believe it's a volume issue.)

**Code for API Data:**

```
const endpoint = 'https://data.seattle.gov/resource/tazs-3rd5.json?$where=report_number%20in(%272020-022388%27,%272020-044620%27)'
const originalplaces = [];
const places = []
fetch(endpoint)
.then(blob => blob.json())
.then(data => originalplaces.push(...data));



async function returnTrue() {


  // create a new promise inside of the async function
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000) // resolve
  });


  // wait for the promise to resolve
  let result = await promise;
  // originalplaces.mcpp === 'MAGNOLIA' && originalplaces.longitude == '0E-9'   && originalplaces.longitude.replace("0E-9", "-122.385973723")
  // originalplaces.forEach(function(mcpp, i) { if (mcpp == 'MAGNOLIA') originalplaces[i] = '47.649387230'; });
  originalplaces.map(object => {

    if (object.mcpp === 'MAGNOLIA' && object.longitude === '0E-9' && object.latitude === '0E-9')

     {  object.longitude = "-122.391970804"
     object.latitude = "47.63103937"
    }


  })
  places.push(...originalplaces)


  console.log(places)


  // console log the result (true)
  console.log(result);
}

// call the function
returnTrue();

export default originalplaces;
```

**Code for Map**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

import places from './crimedata.js'

class MapView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showingInfoWindow: false,
      activeMarker: {},
      selectedPlace: {},

    };
    this.handleMarkerClick = this.handleMarkerClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }



  handleMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: places[props.placeIndex],
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true,

    });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        className={"map"}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 47.6205, lng: -122.3493}}
        style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}
      >

        {places.map((place, i) => {
          return (



            <Marker
              key={i}
              onClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
              position={{
                lat: parseFloat(place.latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(place.longitude)

              }}

              icon={{

                url: place.offense_parent_group === "ASSAULT OFFENSES" ? "/googlemarkersyellow.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "BURGLARY/BREAKING&ENTERING" ?"/googlemarkersdarkorange.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "TRESPASS OF REAL PROPERTY" ?"/googlemarkersorange.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "STOLEN PROPERTY OFFENSES" ?"/googlemarkersgreen.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "SEX OFFENSES" ?"/googlemarkersblack.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "DESTRUCTION/DAMAGE/VANDALISM OF PROPERTY" ?"/googlemarkersdarkgreen.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "DRUG/NARCOTIC OFFENSES" ?"/googlemarkersdarkgray.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "ROBBERY" ?"/googlemarkersdarkpurple.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT " ?"/googlemarkerspink.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "HOMICIDE OFFENSES" ?"/googlemarkersteal.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "ARSON" ?"/googlemarkerslightblue.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "HUMAN TRAFFICKING" ?"/googlemarkersteal.svg"
                : place.offense_parent_group === "PROSTITUTION OFFENSES" ?"/googlemarkerstan.svg"

                : `/googlemarkerdefault.svg`,
                scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(50, 50)
              }}
              placeIndex={i}
              name={place.offense}
            />

          );
        })}

        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.handleClose}

        >
          <div> <h6>{this.state.selectedPlace.offense}</h6>
         <p> {'Crime: ' + this.state.selectedPlace.offense_parent_group}</p>
         <p> {'City: ' + this.state.selectedPlace.mcpp}</p>
         <p> {'Report Date: ' +this.state.selectedPlace.report_datetime}</p>
         <p> {'Report Number: ' + this.state.selectedPlace.report_number}</p>



          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLEMAPS
})(MapView);
```

**Screenshots:**

[Prior to Clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgLya.png)

[AfterClicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJdpj.png)

**Last Notes:**
I have overrides for all the cities, which is why you see 4 pins, in my screenshot, but code only has override for one city, if I include all, it's really long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's a timing issue when importing your `places` data from `crimedata.js` in the first load of the code. I can see that the `places` value is empty [] in the initial run then the loading of your places in your `crimedata.js` will follow after some time. You can see this in the console log in my [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/importingjson-from-endpoint-with-timing-issue-zfxf5t?file=crimedata.js).

To handle this, I used state variables to hold the value of the `updatedPlaces` data then in `componentDidMount` function, I used setTimeOut and set value of `updatedPlaces` state variable from the imported places data that is now available.

I then used this state variable as a condition for the markers to load.

Here's the code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

import places from "./crimedata.js";
console.log("upon importing crimedata.js");
console.log(places);
class MapView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      updatedPlaces: null,
      showingInfoWindow: false,
      activeMarker: {},
      selectedPlace: {}
    };
    this.handleMarkerClick = this.handleMarkerClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(places);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        updatedPlaces: places
      });
      console.log("timeOut in componentDidMount");
      console.log(this.state.updatedPlaces);
    }, 1000);
  }

  handleMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: places[props.placeIndex],
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        className={"map"}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 47.6205, lng: -122.3493 }}
        style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
      >
        {this.state.updatedPlaces != null &&
          this.state.updatedPlaces.map((place, i) => (
            <Marker
              key={i}
              onClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
              position={{
                lat: parseFloat(place.latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(place.longitude)
              }}
              icon={{
                url:
                  place.offense_parent_group === "ASSAULT OFFENSES"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-blank.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group ===
                      "BURGLARY/BREAKING&ENTERING"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/orange-blank.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "TRESPASS OF REAL PROPERTY"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/orange-circle.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "STOLEN PROPERTY OFFENSES"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-blank.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "SEX OFFENSES"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-circle.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group ===
                      "DESTRUCTION/DAMAGE/VANDALISM OF PROPERTY"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/grn-circle.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "DRUG/NARCOTIC OFFENSES"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-stars.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "ROBBERY"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/purple-blank.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT "
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/pink-blank.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "HOMICIDE OFFENSES"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ltblu-blank.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "ARSON"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/blu-blank.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "HUMAN TRAFFICKING"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ltblu-circle.png"
                    : place.offense_parent_group === "PROSTITUTION OFFENSES"
                    ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/T.png"
                    : `http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/red-pushpin.png`,
                scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(50, 50)
              }}
              placeIndex={i}
              name={place.offense}
            />
          ))}

        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <div>
            {" "}
            <h6>{this.state.selectedPlace.offense}</h6>
            <p> {"Crime: " + this.state.selectedPlace.offense_parent_group}</p>
            <p> {"City: " + this.state.selectedPlace.mcpp}</p>
            <p> {"Report Date: " + this.state.selectedPlace.report_datetime}</p>
            <p> {"Report Number: " + this.state.selectedPlace.report_number}</p>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
})(MapView);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through the above. I can confirm that now the pins load consistently on the first load. 

However, when I try and pull the category, rather than a specific crime id, nothing loads.  Example: https://data.seattle.gov/resource/tazs-3rd5.json?offense_parent_group=SEX%20OFFENSES

I do have all the other cities in the code, so I'm not sure why only one pin still shows up, rather than the full 47.

Comment: Hi, 

Actually, I think it is just a limit thing. Thank you!!!!!! When I ran it with   "https://data.seattle.gov/resource/tazs-3rd5.json?$limit=10&offense_parent_group=SEX%20OFFENSES"; then it all showed up.